# How to turn a string entry to blank in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a variable in a data frame that has self-reported locations for a survey. I am trying to recode some entries to blanks because some of the answers include options like "at home" or "in a galaxy far far away". I am in the basic learning steps of R.

I tried using the package "stringr" to make the change but it is not registering in the data frame. It is just giving me a result in the console but nothing changes in the data.

```
stringr::str_remove(grep("home", practice$Location, value=TRUE), " ")
#[1] "home" "hom"
```

I want the final file to have a blank entry where "home" is detected.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If you have `x <- 1` and you run `x + 1`, the result `2` is printedin the console, but `x` is still 1, unchanged. If you want to change `x`, you need to do `x <- x + 1`. Your data frame is just the same. If your code gives you the result you want, and you want it in the data frame, you have to assign it with `<-`. Something like `practice$Locations <- ...your code...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
practice=data.frame(Location=c("Room 1","at home","Room 2"),stringsAsFactors=F)
practice=mutate(practice,Location=if_else(grepl("home",Location),"",Location))
```